# How can I convert an index column and add it back to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My df looks like this:

| Index1 | Index2 | cat | art |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | 1 | 1293874 | Vintage |
| name | 1 | Sam | old |
| id | 2 | 2030039 | Retired |
| name | 2 | Ben | lacklust |

My goal is try to pivot index1 and add them as columns. Currently, my data is not structured and correctly formatted. The category column has a bucket of information of both name and id, but it is not a category.
Not only do I want to group by the index, but I also want to add the columns to the dataset without removing any of the original columns.

My desired output looks like this

| Index2 | cat | name | id_Art | name_Art |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1293874 | Sam | Vintage | old |
| 2 | 2030039 | Ben | Retired | lacklust |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt`:

```
out = (df.melt(['Index1', 'Index2'], var_name='Category', value_name='Value')
         .assign(Category=lambda x: x['Index1'] + '_' + x['Category'])
         .pivot('Index2', 'Category', 'Value')
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
   Index2   id_art   id_cat  name_art name_cat
0       1  Vintage  1293874       old      Sam
1       2  Retired  2030039  lacklust      Ben
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unstack on level=0 (in your case Index1):

```
df.set_index(['Index1', 'Index2'], inplace=True) #make sure your Index1 and Index2 are set are index
print(df.unstack(level=0))
```

Output:

```
            cat           art          
Index1       id name       id      name
Index2                                 
1       1293874  Sam  Vintage       old
2       2030039  Ben  Retired  lacklust
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get to the same result as Tranbi's answer, since you mentioned pivoting:

```
df.pivot(index='Index2', columns='Index1')
```

gives

```
            cat           art          
Index1       id name       id      name
Index2                                 
1       1293874  Sam  Vintage       old
2       2030039  Ben  Retired  lacklust
```